# Is there standard Option or Nullable class in Java?

Tags: java, class, option-type

`Nullable` (C#) has a bit different meaning, but anyway both `Option` (Scala) and `Nullable` can be used to express the notion of "value or nothing".

For example in case when you would like to find substring in a string -- instead of obscure -1 as Int, it would be better to return Option[Int] (in Scala it would be `None` for nothing).

**Is there such class in standard Java? If yes, what it is?**

*Please note, I am not asking how to write such class.*

### Update

As I wrote, `Nullable` has different meaning. Consider this:

Just imagine Map[K,V], and method get which semantics is to get value of key, if there is such key, or nothing when there is no such key.

You cannot use null for two reasons, you cannot use any concrete class for one reason. Option[V] is the way to go.

Comment: Java does not have `Nullable<T>`. Unlike C# that has value types and reference types, adding `Nullable<T>` to Java would not produce a desired effect, at least if added by itself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The primitives in Java *are* value types... just a fixed restricted set of such with no common base :( One of my biggest gripes about `Nullable<T>` is that it is not like `Option`: I was disappointed to see the construct not taken further (or supported with a reference type version) along with some more useful C# language patterns. (Why do we still have to deal with NPEs in 2012? :-/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. *There is no such construct standard in Java.**

There is [Option in FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Option.html) or, as yshavit notes, [Optional in Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)... Or, you could create your own type... but without proper language support... well, let's just say I avoid Java ;-)

Happy coding.

---

*I disagree that `Integer` or `Double` fulfill this role as they only wrap the fixed set of primitives and are not a generic container. They can be considered to cover the case of `Nullable`, simply due to Java's fixed set of value types and C#'s limitation of `Nullable` (only works on ValueTypes), but they do *not* replace a real `Option` type.

Do note however, that the `Option` from FJ or Guava *still uses* (it must, actually) the wrapper types (e.g. `Integer`) for handling primitives. Also note that `Nullable` in C# is not the same as `Option` in Scala due to the aforementioned restriction.

Comment: *"And I disagree that Integer or Double fulfill this role as they only wrap the fixed set of primitives and are not a generic container."* The point is that there are reference types for **all** of the primitive types, and all other types are *already* reference types, and thus `null` is available. So this is an inbuilt feature of Java.

Comment: They don't *replace* `Option` because in Java, you don't *need* `Option`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There are *many things* Java doesn't have because they "aren't needed". That is not a good argument.

Comment: I disagree, but I'll leave it there. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, indeed core Java developers needs are rather limited ;-) However, Integer or Double is not something you agree or not, it is not applicable, period. Just imagine Map[K,V], and method `get` which semantics is to get value of key, if there is such key, or nothing when there is no such key. I am all ears how you do this with Double.

Comment: There is also `Optional` in guava, in case you're already using that.

Comment: @pst, thank you. The limitations of Java is main reason I avoided this language (I use C# in work, and Scala at home) but now I simply have task which require to use Java. Cruel world, I know ;-D.

Comment: @macias: When did this turn into a "down with Java" question? Let's lighten up. If you ask a Java question, trashing the language when people try to help you is...not great. Re your `Map` example: Have the `get` operation return a `Double`. If there is a match in the map, return that `Double`. If there isn't, return `null`. This is bog-standard. Example: http://pastie.org/3643762

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, (1) idea of storing `Person` (for example, V can be any type) in map, and getting always `Double` in return is somewhat strange. (2) when I store null in map, your program would output there is no such data.

Comment: @macias: (1) ?! You said nothing about storing `Person` objects. You asked how to do this with doubles, so I told you. If you want to store disparate types in a `Map`, you can do that too: Just use `Object`, which is a reference type: http://pastie.org/3643815 (2) **Finally**, an actual issue. Yes, if you want to store `null` in the map, then you can't use `null` as a sentinel value. So create an immutable instance to use as that sentinel, `final Object NoValue = new Object();`. Done.

Comment: @yshavit Thanks, I put that useful information in the post :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, (1) I did. It's called generics. (2) uhm, and now how do you use it? Ok, ok, don't answer. Java is not end of the world, there are a lot of programming concepts which Java does not support, and I respect myself, so I won't jump hoops just to prove the broken concept. I already wrote Option. Done! This time for good.

Comment: @macias: (1) I quote: *"I am all ears how you do this with Double"* And so I showed you. No mention of `Person` *or* generics. (2) Follow the link, for cryin' out loud. I **showed** how you use it. *"there are a lot of programming concepts which Java does not support"* There are some, just as in *any* other language. All languages have tradeoffs, they're all stronger in one place and weaker in another. You're clearly married to `Option`, and that's fine. There are many paths to enlightenment.

Answer (score 6):

You asked more than two years ago, but two months ago, Java SE 8 has introduced [`java.util.Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). For an intro, see this Technet article:

[Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the usual way you'd do that would be with `null` and the [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), etc. classes (which are the reference type equivalents of the `int`, `long`, etc. primitive types; being reference types, the references can be `null`). If you have a C# background, `Integer` in Java (with autoboxing) is kind of like `int?` in C#.

For instance, [`List#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) has this signature:

```
int indexOf(Object o)
```

...and does the `-1` thing you're talking about. If you were designing `List` and preferred `null`, you might have defined it as:

```
Integer indexOf(Object o)
```

...and returned `null` rather than `-1` in the "not found" case.

There are these reference type versions of all of the primitive types in Java, and of course, all other types are already reference types so you already have the `null` option.

Comment: Thank you, but you focused on the example, not on question. You cannot use Long/Integer/whatever in generic method.

Comment: @macias: I addressed the whole point of optionality. Can you explain what you mean about not being able to use it in a generic method? If the return type of the generic method is a reference type, you're done. `null` means "no value."

Comment: I have a soured view of Java in general, but the -1 is silly so a +1 for you good sir ;-)