# What is the equivalent of Rust's Option::iter in Java?

Tags: java, rust

I have the following code in Rust and I want to translate it into Java, so I need to understand the code at first.

```
pub struct SimpleSelector {
    pub tag_name: Option<String>,
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub class: Vec<String>,
}

impl Selector {
    pub fn specificity(&self) -> Specificity {
        // http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity
        let Selector::Simple(ref simple) = *self;
        let a = simple.id.iter().len();
        let b = simple.class.len();
        let c = simple.tag_name.iter().len();
        (a, b, c)
    }
}
```

I am facing problem in this line of code:

```
let a = simple.id.iter().len();
```

Comment: Parent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461207/what-does-string-iter-do-in-rust. Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23873769/257568.

Comment: So `a` is 0 if the id is "None", and 1 if it is a "Some". There are clearer ways to write that! For example `self.id.is_some() as uint`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Option<String>` has a value, then its iterator will have one element to iterate over.

If the `Option<String>` has no value, then its iterator will have 0 elements to iterate.

In other words `a` in `let a = simple.id.iter().len();` is the count of elements in `simple.id`, which is either 1 if there is an id and 0 if there isn't.

(The actual calculation of the `len` happens in `Item.size_hint`, you can see it's source [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2bfb64e5252179b5bd6d8a2e96664ca97a2496f3/src/libcore/option.rs#L789)).

If Java you could either use `null`, as in

```
public class SimpleSelector {
  public String tag_name;
  public String id;
  public ArrayList<String> clazz;
}
// ...
int a = id == null ? 0 : 1;
```

or [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) from Java 8, as in

```
public class SimpleSelector {
  public Optional<String> tag_name;
  public Optional<String> id;
  public ArrayList<String> clazz;
}
// ...
int a = id.empty() ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @ArtemGr's answer, you can also think of `Option` as a collection that can only hold 0 or 1 values. The Java code might look like:

```
public class SimpleSelector {
  public ArrayList<String> tag_name;
  public ArrayList<String> id;
  public ArrayList<String> clazz;
}
// ...
int a = id.size();
```

Using `null` would be many people's first choice as an equivalent, but it has a downside compared to `Option`. In Rust, this will never compile:

```
fn thing(id: Option<String>) {
  id.len(); // id could be `Some` or `None`!
}
```

But the `null`-using equivalent in Java would compile but might blow up at runtime:

```
public static void thing(String id) {
  id.length();  // id could be null or not-null!
}
```